# Child divs containing images and text have height but parent div does not

Tags: html, css, razor, sass

I have some divs created in a cshtml file dynamically "favorite-item". They contain an item div which contains a img and span tag which are generated dynamically by a model. Most items load instantly but some take some time. During this time, on slower mobile phones, you can see the icons bunched up on the bottom of the whole encompassing parent div. The parent div and the favorite-item child divs have a height of 0 even though some of the images and spans have a height and some do not. They should be laid out in a block format of about 2 columns of images wide.

Here is the cshtml:

```
<div class="MyFavorites" style="position: relative;">
<h5 class="title-section">@Model.MyFavoriteTitle</h5>
@if (Model.MyFavoriteCustomizeLink != null)
{
    <a href="@Model.MyFavoriteCustomizeLink.Url" class="favorites-customize"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i></a>
}
<div class="row collapse panel favorites">
    <div class="row" data-equalizer>
        @if (Model.FavoriteLinks != null && Model.FavoriteLinks.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model.FavoriteLinks.Where(link => !link.IsDeleted))
            {
                var url = (item.LinkUrl ?? String.Empty).Trim();
                var target = (item.LinkTarget ?? String.Empty).Trim();
                if (item != null && item.FavoriteIcon != null) //temporary fix for null issues
                {
                    var fi = item.FavoriteIcon;
                    <div class="column small-6 favorite-item" data-equalizer-watch>
                        <a href="@url" target="@target" class="item">
                            @if (fi != null && fi.FavoriteIconImage != null)
                            {
                                @RenderImage(item, o => o.FavoriteIcon.FavoriteIconImage, new { Class = "icon" }, isEditable: false);
                            }
                            <span>@item.FavoriteTitle</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <p class="column empty-list-message">@Html.Raw(UtilityHelpers.SafeRichTextHtml(Model.MyFavoriteListEmptyMessage_HomePage))</p>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the scss:

```
@include breakpoint(small only) {
.item-container {
    display: none; // hide by default
    margin-right: -0.71429rem !important;
    margin-left: -0.71429rem !important;
}

.show-mobile {
    display: block !important;
}

.panel.favorites {
    padding: 1.25em 2.75em;
}

.favorites .favorite-item {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 1.1em;

    .item {
        display: block;
    }

    .item > img {
        display: block;
        max-width: 85%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Why am I getting a height of 0 for the favorite item div? What is the fix to not have them all the favorite-item divs bunched in the bottom of the parent "Favorites" div? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The secret sauce is that the class "favorite-item" needed an "overflow: hidden" attribute. Even though these are not floating children, this acts like floating children thanks to the MVC objects. Also, the model does not give a height until all of the items are loaded (and there is no event to tell us when that happens... not even the document "ready" event), so we have to poll the child item objects to check their heights.